# how can i list from an array and adding greed of images in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWj89.jpg)Hi mates i have an array of books and For each book, i should create a

element with the book title and author and append it to the page and i need to add  an image to each book

```
const books = [
  {
    title: "book1",
    author: "x"},
  {
    title: "book2",
    author: "y"

  },
  {
    title: "book3",
    author: "z"
      }
];
```

here is my code :

```
function myfunction(books) {
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
   var book =content.appendChild(document.createElement('P'))
   var list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'))
   book.appendChild(list);
   var item = content.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
   book.appendChild(document.createTextNode(books.title));
   item.appendChild(book);
   }
}
```

but it's not working is undefined :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IqrZ.jpg

i just need the form and should look smilar to :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEtL3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's a small example, you confuse `html` and you didn't use `books[i]`, instead of `appenChild` i used `innerHTML`.

```js
const books = [{
    title: "book1",
    author: "x"
  },
  {
    title: "book2",
    author: "y"

  },
  {
    title: "book3",
    author: "z"
  }
];
myfunction(books);

function myfunction(books) {
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  let list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    let book = item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    book.innerHTML = books[i].title + '-' + books[i].author + '<br><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">';

  }
}
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: That was useful.
How to add a diffrent photo to each book?

Comment: Put the link into object books and use it into code like other.